# dropdown-menu bootstrap . Несколько выпадающих меню

Tags: html, bootstrap

```html
<script src="http://cat.hr00.ru/demo/8.5-adaptive/templates/adaptive/script/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cat.hr00.ru/demo/8.5-adaptive/templates/adaptive/boostrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cat.hr00.ru/demo/8.5-adaptive/templates/adaptive/boostrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='btn pull-left ' data-toggle="dropdown"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></span> Параметры1</div>
<div class='dropdown-menu'>test1</div>

<div class='btn pull-left ' data-toggle="dropdown"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></span> Параметры2</div>
<div class='dropdown-menu'>test2</div>
```

как сделать 2 разных меню, чтобы раздельно работали ? Данный пример выводит только одну менюшку по двум кнопкам . Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <div class='btn pull-left ' data-toggle="dropdown"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></span> Параметры1</div>
  <div class='dropdown-menu'>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Test 1</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
  <div class='btn pull-left ' data-toggle="dropdown"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog'></span> Параметры2</div>
  <div class='dropdown-menu'>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Test 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/waqitaweju/edit?html,output)